# How to get session object in Microsoft azure bot sdk 4.0 in node.js?

Tags: botframework

Attaching the code snippet below. UniversalBot and ChatConnector has been deprecated in botbuilder 4.1.5.

```
var bot;
try {
    bot = new BasicBot(conversationState, userState, botConfig);
} catch (err) {
    console.error(`[botInitializationError]: ${ err }`);
    process.exit();
}

// Create HTTP server
// let server = restify.createServer();
let server = express();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function() {
    console.log(`\n${ server.name } listening to ${ server.url }`);
    console.log(`\nGet Bot Framework Emulator: https://aka.ms/botframework-emulator`);
    console.log(`\nTo talk to your bot, open basic-bot.bot file in the Emulator`);
});

// Listen for incoming activities and route them to your bot main dialog.
server.post('/api/messages', (req, res) => {
    // Route received a request to adapter for processing
    adapter.processActivity(req, res, async (turnContext) => {
        // route to bot activity handler.
        await bot.onTurn(turnContext);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is fairly general.

The session object from 3.x has been removed. Instead acccessors are used. You will want to do following in the bot class:

```
    public onTurn = async (turnContext: TurnContext) => {
        const userProfile = await this.userProfile.get(turnContext, new UserProfile());
        const conversationData = await this.dialogStateAccessor.get(turnContext, { dialogStack: undefined });

        // set vars in cache
        userProfile.yourUserVarProp = "userValue";
        conversationData.yourConversationVarProp = "conversationValue";

        // persist userVars through dialog turn
        await this.userProfile.set(turnContext, userProfile);

        // persist conversationVars through dialog turn
        await this.dialogStateAccessor.set(turnContext, conversationData);


        //
        // -> your dialogs here (await dc.beginDialog("dialogname");)
        //


        // save uservars to db at end of a turn
        await this.userState.saveChanges(turnContext);
        // save conversationVars to db at end of a turn
        await this.conversationState.saveChanges(turnContext);
    }
```

But there is some additional constructor stuff

- @param {ConversationState} conversationState A ConversationState object used to store the dialog state.
- @param {UserState} userState A UserState object used to store values specific to the user.

... and creating the userProfile and dialogStateAccessor itself.

For the whole picture have better a look at https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/javascript_nodejs .

Or try the generator: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/javascript/bot-builder-javascript-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0.